Adding a role to user from client Id string?
I am creating my discord.js bot along side my express.js app and have a validation page that requires the user to submit their unique code generated when they join the discord server, in other words I would like to add a role to the guild member when they have successfully input the code on the webapp.
I have a database collecting their user id. Is there a way I can fetch a guild member from their user id to add to a role in my "guild"/discord server? I have attempted numerous ways to fetch the user to set a role though it will log Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cache') no matter what method I am using. Any help in the right direction would be great, I have left the source code to said project below along with the validation page I am using to validate the code that is generated on GuildMemberAdd.
Regards,
codibez
GitHub repository | validation page

As far as I understand, you want to get data from your site with the user ID like the data in the GuildMember class.
This is only possible with OAuth2. However, it may be possible to establish a connection between your bot and your website with another method.
When someone joins the server, you can keep this person in memory, just like you create code when someone joins the server.
I gave an example with the ‘node-cache’ library below.
/lib/cache.js
// Create a file called cache.js in a lib file.
const NC= require("node-cache");
const codes = new NC({ stdTTL: 0 });

module.exports = codes

membedAdd.js
const codes = require("../../lib/cache.js");
// ...
const code = getRandomStr();
codes.set(code, member.id)

indexController.js
// update role
if(codes.has(request.body.code)) codes.del(request.body.code) // This will trigger the ‘del’ event.

app.js
// ...
codes.on(‘del’, (key, value) => {
   // From here you can now access the client. And you can easily assign roles to anyone you want.
  })
// ...

Risks
Since this information is kept in memory, the information will be lost if the bot is switched off and on. Therefore, you can trigger an event when closing the bot and save the data in memory to a file.
